# MS Word filename from bookmarks with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Assuming I have:

- a word template including macro: **custom_template.dotm**;
- two bookmarks in this template: '**first_name**" and "**last_name**".

I would like that on "Save" event, in the dialog box, the application proposes to user, instead of "document1", and only if relative bookmarks exist, the filename "**Document of first_name second_name.docx**".

Can anybody explain me how to achieve this with VBA?

Thanks.

=== UPDATE ===

Now I've this code, working well when I execute it.
I would like it runs automatically when user clicks on "save document".

```
Sub Demo()
Dim sFlNm As String
With ActiveDocument
  sFlNm = "Document of " & .Bookmarks("first_name").Range.Text & " " & .Bookmarks("last_name").Range.Text
End With
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
  .Name = sFlNm
  .Show
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't a tutorial or free coding site. Start by searching online for code, Including the phrase _Word VBA_ to narrow down the results. _Word VBA get bookmarks set variable_ and _Word VBA display save dialog_ should get you close. Assemble a macro, then post here for help with debugging.

Comment: John is correct as to how Stack Overflow works. Separate your search into two components both with "Word vba" in the search. One search is for "get bookmark information data" and the other for "save saveas filename." *If you ask the same question on the Microsoft Answers Community forum, chances are someone will give you a macro.* http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word

Comment: @JohnKorchok I've already done many researches on web, without a working solution. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

For a macro to run at the client's end, you would have to send a macro-enabled template or document. Many people who are running anti-virus software will get a warning of a possible Word virus. Then the user will have to manually enable the macros. Are they going to bother?

Making it run automatically with a Save command may have unintended consequences. You'll have to check whether the bookmarks have actually been filled, and using the Save command while you're revising the document can save it with a new file name. But you asked, so here's how: rename the macro as **FileSave**. Then when you choose **Ctrl + S** or **File>Save** in Word, the dialog will automatically pop up:

```
Sub FileSave()
    Dim sFlNm As String
    With ActiveDocument
      sFlNm = "Document of " & .Bookmarks("first_name").Range.Text & " " & .Bookmarks("last_name").Range.Text
    End With
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
      .Name = sFlNm
      .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

In Word, to create a macro that runs automatically when you choose a Word command, follow these steps:

1. Choose **Developer>Macros**.
2. Change the *Macros in* dropdown to **Word commands**.
3. Choose the command name you want to re-purpose.
4. Change the *Macros in* dropdown back to the macro-enabled document or template that you're developing.
5. Click on the **Create** button. A new macro is created in the VBE with the correct command name. Fill in the macro with whatever you want the macro to do.

Comment: Another reference on intercepts: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm